# karama fake async tick not working as expected

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

here is the hopefully relevant parts of the test. This test works 100% if I add a setTimeout but ideally don't want to have to do that. I want to have the test wait a certain amount of time before checking the template, what is happening now is its checking too quick and the ngIf check in the template fails so the check fails. Have tried quite a few things and combinations of manually calling done, and using fixture.whenStable() cannot seem to get anything to work except setTimeout

I guess I am expecting tick() to fast forward 1.5 seconds without actually stalling javascript while some async tasks are run in this case it the 2nd observable in combineLatest

```
 mockCycleService = jasmine.createSpyObj('CycleService', ['getPageDuration', 'nextPage'])
    mockCycleService.getPageDuration.and.returnValue(800);
    mockCycleService.nextPage.and.returnValue(of());

  fit('should display a blog post', fakeAsync(() => {
    // setTimeout(()=>{
    
    tick(1500); //larger than set timeout have tried so many higher numbers 
    fixture.detectChanges();
      const cards = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('.csCard'));
      console.log(cards)
      expect(cards).not.toBeNull();
      expect(cards.length).toEqual(1);
    // },70)
  }));
```

here is the component, basically its getting a list of blogs and then combining this with a timer to rotate content of the blog posts

```
this.timerSubscription$ = timer(1,this.cycleService.getPageDuration());
 this.blogs$ = combineLatest([this.blogPosts$, this.timerSubscription$]).pipe(
      tap(console.log), //this fires in console log after cards in test
      map(r => r[0].map(a => a)),
      tap(() => this.curInd = this.curInd + 1),
      takeWhile((response) => this.curInd < response.length),
      finalize(() => this.cycleService.nextPage())
    );
```

the template handles subscribing ...

```
<div *ngIf="blogs$ | async as blogs">
  <div class="csCard" *ngFor="let blog of blogs>
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you need to try combinations of things when using `fakeAsync` for timing issues e.g.

```js
tick()
fixture.detectChanges();
flush();
fixture.detectChanges();
```

If you're calling `fixture.detectChanges();` more than once it only works with `Default` change detection strategy not `OnPush` - but this can be overridden in `TestBed` if needs be

Comment: Yeah have tried this before and several other combos but no luck